# Disable multipath while installing ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation

I have some problem while installing any ubuntu based distro
I have following setup
1 SSD drive with Windows
2 * 500 Gb drives ( same manufacturer etc.)

Whenever I try to install any ubuntu based distro, those 2 disks are detected as Mutlipath 
(/dev/mapper). I can't install anything, as one of those disks is empty , one has some important data and stuff. When I disconnect one drive , then ubuntu setup sees it coretly and I can install linux without any problem. If I reconnect drive, linux fails to start ( multipath is loaded and it fails to find linux files )
Tried to plug in one drive into other slots on MB but still detected as multipath.

I even tried to install multipath-tools ( using terminal sudo apt-get install multipath-tools ) then in setup I was able to see all partitions on my drives , but disk were listed twice, once as /dev/mapper and once as /dev/sdb . Any attempt to install ( either on mapper or sdb ) resulted in some strange errors ( once it was failed to create swap on mapper , another time I just got "????" in message window

Any help, on how to disable this multipath and allowing to install ubuntu based distros would be welcome :)

UPDATE: It's clearly ubuntu installer issue. I just installed debian on same configuration without any problems. Hovever I'd prefer ubuntu , as it's more user friendly and less problems with dirvers etc.

Comment: In the same position, seems like my disks are becoming a single disk that's equivalent to just one of my NVMe drives while I use my Hyper M.2 x16 Gen 4 Card.

I've removed the multipath after the installer has started (get into the shell, `multipath -F`) but they just don't show up after that.

Answer (score 1):

To disable multipath:

```
multipath -f <path>
```

as per: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19122-01/j4500.array/820-3163/bcghjife.html#bcgcabjj

Comment: Unfortunately this is not helping. I installed multipath-tools, then sudo multipath -f <path> of both drives ( first try on one, then on second) the only difference now is that /dev/mapper disks were shown as they were without multipath-tools , but /dev/sdb drive was also visible with partition.
When tried to install on /dev/sdb1 , got error 
creation of swap space in partition #6 of SCSI4(sdb) failed - so the same I got at the start - disk are not usable

Comment: When you say "When I disconnect one drive, then ubuntu setup sees it correctly", what exactly do you mean by 'correctly'?  If you are using LVM, then multipath pathing will be used, so if they are coming up under /dev/mapper that is not necessarily a bad thing - how are you partitioning the devies?  Can you clarify your disk setup?  You mention 1 SSD drive and 2 * 500gb drives - so there are 3 disks total?  which drive(s) are you trying to install ubuntu onto?

Comment: Yes I have 3 disks in total 
I'm trying to install on one of 500 Gb disks let's call it A. 
There is second disk ( same manufacturer , bough together with disk A ) let's call it B.

Problem for ubuntu is that those 2 500 GB disks appear as multipath for him. I need data on disk B and install linux on A. Can't do it if both disks are plugged in . If I disconnect disk B (open PC case, and take out power for disk B ) then disk A is seen as normal disk and can make partitions ( or reuse existing ones ) and install linux  without problems.

Comment: As for instalation process, I launch LVM setup, choose "Something else" when asked for instalation ( don't trust the automatic install next to windows 8 option), then I take disk A, try to create partition 100Gb for ext4 root , 1 Gb for swap, rest of disk leave in FAT32 to be common for linux and windows

Comment: Okay, so you're saying that the installer thinks your two 500gb disks are a single device, with multiple paths?  There is a similar question here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97089/local-disks-detected-as-multipath-device  I'm going to suggest you post in that community where you might get better help